# update dependency of a property in loops

Tags: c#, wpf, callback

I got a foreach loop, where I update a property of the objects. This property has a dependency which I update in the setter. This seems to slow my application, because the dependency takes some time and would have to be updated only once, after the foreach loop.

It is not recommended to call the update of the dependency after the loop, because the setter is used in many other places in my code. Beyond that, the object should be responsible to update it's dependency and not the calling function.

code example for clarity

```
//anywhere else in my other classes
private Foo[] objects;

public void UpdateFoo()
{
  //update propably hundrets of small objects
  foreach (Foo obj in objects)
  {
    obj.Property = 1;
  }
}

class Foo
{
  private int _property;
  public int Property 
  { 
    get { return _property; } 
    set
    {
      _property = value;

      //Update something anywhere else
      StaticBigFoo.Update();
    } }
}

class StaticBigFoo
{
  public static void Update()
  {
    //do something longer
  }
}
```

I'm wondering what's best practice for this szenario?

- I could use a `DependencyProperty` and it's PropertyChanged-Callback, but then the dependency would still be updated every time.
- I thought about starting something in the Dispatcher with `DispatcherPriority.Background` and filter it for distinct delegates (but how?)
- I could use some transactional logic, but I do not know what to use there. I read something about `TransactionScope`, can I use it for something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a section defined by `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()` calls as provided by several GUI elements. What I mean is something like the following:

```
class Foo
{
  private int _property;
  public int Property 
  { 
    get { return _property; } 
    set
    {
      _property = value;

      if(inUpdate)
        propertyChanged = true;
      else
        //Update something anywhere else
        StaticBigFoo.Update();
    } }

    static bool inUpdate = false;
    static bool propertyChanged;
    public static void BeginUpdate() { inUpdate = true; propertyChanged = false; }
    public static void EndUpdate() { inUpdate = false; if(propertyChanged) StaticBigFoo.Update(); }
}
```

And then

```
Foo.BeginUpdate();    
foreach (Foo obj in objects)
{
  obj.Property = 1;
}
Foo.EndUpdate();
```

That allows to defer the update if needed.

Comment: I guess I will need some transaction-like stuff like Begin() & End(), though I will rewrite my setter to keep it clean like denis morozov said. I'll accept this one, too bad I can't accept a merged version of your both answers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just a food for thought, properties are mainly used to get/set values of a field in a controlled fashion. Or in your case, an extra mile more which is change notification. Arguably, can have validations,lazy loading.  But it seems you are doing lot more than that within the setter, which I not a best practice. Why because, we likely to access properties more often, which cause the properties to be evaluated hence the underlying logic .

Answer (score 1):

I would leave setters clean and in them do just the field assignement and PropertyChanged. Then listen to PropertyChanged and do the extra stuff there (in a separate thread if you want - using task here for simplicity);

```
class Foo
{
 //constructor
 public Foo()
 {
    PropertyChanged += (s,args) =>
    {
       switch(args.PropertyName)
       {
          case "Property" :
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { StaticBigFoo.Update();});
            break;
         ....

 public int Property
 { get ...
 {
   set  
   {
      if(_property == value) return;
      _property = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => Property);
    ......
```

Comment: I like this one, but it calls Update for every property change, though it's in a new task.

Comment: another thought, if you don't like to listen to all property changed. How about creating a specific private event "UpdateStaticBigFoo", raise it inside of you property and listen to it.. Same idea, except for now it only fires once when that property changes